# How to filter items updated since a specific date in podio

Tags: podio

I am trying to retrieve all items from my Podio app that were updated since a specific date.

I tried the https://api.podio.com/item/app/{id}/filter API filtering on the `last_event_on` attribute but the API returns `"error_description": "Invalid value \"last_event_on\" (string): Invalid filtering key"`

How can I achieve this ?

I could create a View with updated items since Yesterday and call the API `/item/app/{app_id}/filter/{view_id}/` everyday but it does not seem robust. I would rather pass specificaly the date of my last call to the API.

Nicolas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution within the documentation.
The available filters are listed within the View doc and not the filter one : https://developers.podio.com/doc/filters

Filter using the `last_edit_on` key which differs from the `last_event_on`in the response.

```
{
"filters":{
  "last_edit_on": {
    "from": "2017-07-10 18:27:03"
  }
}
}
```